# Best design for windows forms sharing a database?

Tags: .net, sql, winforms, network-programming

I plan to develop a windows forms application (or possibly WPF), which may be installed/distributed on many computers all on one network.

These apps will access one SQL database between them.

What's the typical approach to this sort of solution?

The following is what I've come up with so far:

- All accessing a web-hosted SQL db
- Every installation comes with the option to also install a db (only first one needs this), the installation provides the user with an IP to the db, then all other apps on the network can reference this db

I'm not asking for an opinion as I know that's against the SO rules, I'm asking what the single best way of achieving this is.

Comment: Usually, there is a dedicated database server in the network, and the database is hosted only there. Each client having its own database sounds like a bad idea; you'll then have to start thinking about whether they need to be synchronized/merged regularly, so that each client has complete data if other clients go offline.

Comment: @stakx - why isn't this a proposed answer? Appreciate the reply mate, post your answer so you can get some well-deserved upvotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, when several clients need to access the same database, there is a dedicated database server somewhere in the network which will host the database. This will be the *only* place where the database is hosted; the clients don't get their own copy.

> <sub>**Side note:** In the above, I am not considering  scenarios where a database is distributed over several servers. This is usually only necessary when a database becomes very big, or when high availability is very important. In such situations, a database might be fully *replicated* on different database servers in various geographic locations, or a technique called *sharding* might be used to split it up into smaller databases, each of which only has some of the data. (I suppose there are other reasons or techniques for distributing a database, but as said, let's not consider these for the moment.)</sub>

Each client having its own copy of the database sounds like a bad idea, because you'll then have to start thinking about issues such as:

- whether or not the various copies need to be synchronized/merged regularly, so that each client has complete data if other clients go offline;
- what should happen when the different databases contain contradictory information;
- how to protect sensitive data residing in the database, such as user passwords. This is always an issue, but it becomes more difficult when each client could directly access a local database file; it's easier to protect such data on your central database server, e.g. by "hiding" it behind a service façade.

So, put your database on a central database server, and have your clients connect to it; either directly to the database, or via a (possibly secured) SOAP/REST service.

Comment: Thanks again stakx. With what you've said in mind (that there should be one server) - should the installation of this application be different on one particular machine (the chosen server)? Or should it be that all installations are exactly the same and packaged in the same way but one machine has the SQL database restored onto it? i.e. how do I package and distribute the application and installation files to achieve the approach you've suggested?

Comment: Well, except in (a) a small network without a dedicated server, or (b) a testing environment, you would typically not run the client application on a database server at all! On the server, you'd only have to set up the database. So in the end, you would have two very different installation procedures/programs: 1. the installation of the application on client machines; 2. the installation and initial data loading of the database on the server machine.

Comment: Sorry stakx, my apologies, I should've give more context. There'll definitely be no dedicated server, this will be 5 machines (at the most) all on the same network. All machines, I'm to assume, will be of similar spec, but assuming I've chosen one as the server - is it recommended that I provide an option during installation (the same installation as every other machine will get) that the user can 'tick' to say this particular installation is a 'server installation' for example?

Comment: Uh, that depends on your needs. I would suggest that the DB setup be completely separate from the client application setup. (Otherwise it'll be too easy for the users to accidentally install the DB when they don't need it. But that may or may not be an issue for you.) However, your client application setup will probably require an option whereby the user selects the machine that has the DB... unless you can decide this up-front and hardwire the DB host name.

Comment: Thanks a lot Stakx, you've been a real help. Last quick question, and I could be being lazy here to be honest (I'll google it too), but does SQL come with a way of making the installation and restoration of an existing database easy and 'client-friendly' when shipping with applications? Is there a installation creation wizard sort of thing I can be using for this?

Comment: @DeeMac: That would be a whole different question, and I cannot fully answer that one. But remember, SQL Server is not something that your users should have to face. Usually administering SQL Server is left to a DBA (database administrator), not to the end users. So you are perhaps having wrong expectations there.

Answer (score 4):

Consider a web service hosted within your network to do all DB access (calls). This truely separates your database from the client. The app.config of the client would hold the url of the service.

Answer (score 1):

A "web hosted" database is not a good idea. If your application will run in a set of computers within a Local Area Network, the best approach you can use is to set up a SQL Sever within that network.